# Undefined control sequence in align

Tags: align, math-operators

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:x}
x = \sign{a} \cdotp \sign{b} \cdotp \min(\lvert a \rvert,\lvert b \rvert)
\end{align}
```

Above gives me *Undefined control sequence*. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Can you turn your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? It'll help both you and anyone that might be able to help :)

Comment: Yes, forgot to add newcommand in this file. Thanks @Werner . This raises another question, can newcommand be added to master file and used in file which are included from master file ?

Comment: @mishr: Yes, the "master" file could have a bunch of definitions that can be used by other parts. As long as it is loaded before the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a [hint from egreg](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/7UnzVZhjsnc/discussion), add

```
\newcommand*{\sign}{\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}\nolimits}
```

to your document preamble which would provide a `sign` operator. However, since you're loading [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath),

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
```

would be more robust.